# Android: How to stop media player onclick of a button

Tags: android, media-player

I have a play and stop button. When I run the following codes, Play button goes well. But when I click the stop button, I'm getting a force close message.

I'm new to android dev. Many thanks in advance! :)

```
package com.example.hellomedia;

import java.io.IOException;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloMedia extends Activity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HelloMedia.this, R.raw.nicholas);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        final TextView customTextBG = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customTextBG);
        final TextView customTextHL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customTextHL);

        customTextBG.setText("Nicholas was… \n\nOlder than sin, ");
        customTextHL.setText("");

        final String words[] = {
                "Nicholas ", // 0
                "was... \n\n", // 1
                "Older ", // 2
                "than ", // 3
                "sin, ", // 4
        };

        final long startEndTime[][]={
                {   //start time
                    1148,// 0,0
                    1826, // 0,1
                    2766,// 0,2
                    3079,// 0,3
                    3549,// 0,4

                },
                {   //end time
                    1357,// 1,0
                    2192, // 1,1
                    3027,// 1,2
                    3183,// 1,3
                    3966,// 1,4
                }
            };



        customTextBG.setText("Nicholas was… \n\nOlder than sin, ");
        customTextHL.setText("");




        View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.widget30: // PLAY

                        if( !mPlayer.isPlaying() ){

                            try {
                                mPlayer.prepare();
                            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            mPlayer.start();

                            mHandler.post(new Runnable(){

                                    public void run(){ 
                                    final long currentPos = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

                                        int x = 0;
                                        while( x < 102){
                                            if( currentPos > startEndTime[0][x] && currentPos < startEndTime[1][x] ){//0
                                            customTextHL.append(words[x]);
                                            words[x]="";
                                        }
                                        x++;
                                    } mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1);
                                    }

                              });
                        }

                        break;

                    case R.id.widget31: // RESET

                        mHandler.post(new Runnable(){

                            public void run(){ 
                                customTextBG.setText("Nicholas was… \n\nOlder than sin, ");
                                customTextHL.setText("");
                            }

                      });

                        mPlayer.stop();
                        mPlayer.release();

                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        // BUTTONS
        findViewById(R.id.widget30).setOnClickListener(handler); // PLAY
        findViewById(R.id.widget31).setOnClickListener(handler); // RESET

    }
}
```

**My main.xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widget29"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<TextView
android:textStyle="bold" 
android:id="@+id/customTextBG" 
android:textSize="18sp" 
android:text="@+id/customTextBG" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/widget31"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:textStyle="bold" 
android:id="@+id/customTextHL" 
android:textSize="18sp" 
android:text="@+id/customTextHL" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/widget31"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:textColor="#00FF00"
>
</TextView>
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/widget30"
android:text="@string/reset" android:id="@+id/widget31">
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/widget30"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:text="@string/play">
</Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you provide an error message? Either by using the Debug Bridge (adb) or by running the program in the emulator.

Comment: I'm running it in a table PC, how can I see the error message? I'm not using an emulator, It's kinda slow...

Comment: This page explains adb in a nice and easy way: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

Comment: I mean **tablet**, not table. Sorry for my mistake :)

Comment: What I'm doing is, I transfer the .apk file from my pc to my tablet pc (android device). And then install it there... How can I see the runtime error in that case?

Comment: To put it simple: Connect your device with your PC via a USB cable and use adb to display the error messages. Its all explained in the link I posted above. Just read it, It's worth it, as it makes developing software for android much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try without:

```
mHandler.post(new Runnable(){

    public void run(){ 
        customTextBG.setText("Nicholas was… \n\nOlder than sin, ");
        customTextHL.setText("");
    }

});
```

and code for stop player:

```
if(mPlayer.isPlaying())
{
    mPlayer.stop();
}
```

and second, can you provide your xmlfiles, then we can test it and see the errors.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You may now see my main.xml codes on the question. I tried it without those codes. I got the same force close message.

Comment: first error what i have it's 03-29 10:04:13.227: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(907): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
. when i fixed it ( delete for me ) next error was after stop on "mPlayer.release()" i commented it - and all ok . hope it's help u

Comment: thanks for trying it out man! but may i ask what part did you delete? And you commented "mPlayer.release()" code is that what you mean.

Comment: mPlayer.stop();
//mPlayer.release();

Comment: oh yeah! i didn't receive the force close message but when I press the play button again. it doesn't play.

Comment: if( currentPos > startEndTime[0][x] && currentPos < startEndTime[1][x] ){//0  in this line i have error :  ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2461): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException . Can't fix it :( i commented this block - player work perfectly (start,stop,start ets) but this error can't fix .

Comment: if release() not commented - error when u click on stop button is : IllegalStateException.From develeop.com - is thrown to prevent programming errors such as calling prepare(), prepareAsync(), or one of the overloaded setDataSource methods in an invalid state.

Answer (score 1):

Put a try catch block like this -

```
try { 
       mPlayer.stop();
       mPlayer.release(); 
  } catch(Exception ex) { 
     ex.printStackTrace() 
  }
```

If your device is set to debug applications put a breakpoint in the catch block and let us know what the exception says. You can also use the emulator to debug.

Comment: it's class for alert : public void alert(String message)
    {
     new AlertDialog.Builder(this)  
      .setMessage(message)  
       .setTitle("Warning!!!")  
        .setCancelable(true)
              .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,  
               new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){}  
           }) .show();    
    } ////    than in catch block just do it ... catch(IOException e){alert(""+e);    and than if u have crash error - alert can show this error.. It's if u can't see logcat

Comment: @Peter If mPlayer.Release() is not called won't that be a memory leak.Also mPlayer should be set to null after calling release otherwise it will throw an exception when you use it the next time.

Answer (score 1):

The Above code is modified as following code and gets output as per your requirement.When you are create a mediaplayer throuh MediaPlayer.create(....) Method ,no need to prepare again it. Once release or reset Methods are used,they should be required to re-intialize the datasource.

```
public class HelloMedia extends Activity {
   MediaPlayer mPlayer;
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

             mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HelloMedia .this, R.raw.sleepaway);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        final TextView customTextBG = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customTextBG);
        final TextView customTextHL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customTextHL);

        customTextBG.setText("Nicholas was… \n\nOlder than sin, ");
        customTextHL.setText("");

        final String words[] = {
                "Nicholas ", // 0
                "was... \n\n", // 1
                "Older ", // 2
                "than ", // 3
                "sin, ", // 4
        };

        final long startEndTime[][]={
                {   //start time
                    1148,// 0,0
                    1826, // 0,1
                    2766,// 0,2
                    3079,// 0,3
                    3549,// 0,4

                },
                {   //end time
                    1357,// 1,0
                    2192, // 1,1
                    3027,// 1,2
                    3183,// 1,3
                    3966,// 1,4
                }
            };



        customTextBG.setText("Nicholas was… \n\nOlder than sin, ");
        customTextHL.setText("");




        View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.widget30: // PLAY
                        try{
                            if(mPlayer==null)
                                 mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HelloMedia .this, R.raw.sleepaway);
                        if( !mPlayer.isPlaying() )
                        {

                          if(!mPlayer.isPlaying())
                            mPlayer.start();

            mHandler.post(new Runnable(){

                             public void run(){ 
                                 if(mPlayer!=null)
                                 if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                                    final long currentPos = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                                        int x = 0;
                                        while( x < 5){
                                            if( currentPos > startEndTime[0][x] && currentPos < startEndTime[1][x] ){//0
                                            customTextHL.append(words[x]);
                                            words[x]="";
                                        }
                                        x++;
                                    } mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1);
                                    }

                             }});
                        }
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }

                        break;

                    case R.id.widget31: // RESET

                        mHandler.post(new Runnable(){

                            public void run(){ 
                                customTextBG.setText("Nicholas was… \n\nOlder than sin, ");
                                customTextHL.setText("");
                            }

                      });

                        try{
                        if(mPlayer.isPlaying())
                        {
                              mPlayer.stop();
                              mPlayer.reset();
                              mPlayer=null;
                        }
                        }catch (Exception e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }


                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        // BUTTONS
        findViewById(R.id.widget30).setOnClickListener(handler); // PLAY
        findViewById(R.id.widget31).setOnClickListener(handler); // RESET

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's my code, tested and working fine:**

```
package com.example.com.mak.mediaplayer;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final MediaPlayer mpp;
mpp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.red); //mp3 file in res/raw folder
    Button btnplay=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnplay); //Play
        btnplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View vone) {
                mpp.start();}
        });
    Button btnpause=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnpause); //Pause
        btnpause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View vtwo) {
                if(mpp.isPlaying())
                {
        mpp.pause();
        mpp.seekTo(0);
                }
            }
        });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mPlayer != null){
 mPlayer.release();
```

}