# Find out what MediaPlayer is playing and stop it onPause or onStop?

Tags: android, media-player

Does anyone know a good way to find out what `MediaPlayer` is currently playing and stop/pause it using the `onStop()` or `onPause()` override? Or just stop `MediaPlayer` when the app is in the background? I have lots of sounds and I don't know which will be playing at any exact moment. Sorry, still learning here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect to Music app on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522409/connect-to-music-app-on-android)

Comment: still was unable to figure out how to do this. Right now I have a huge else if going on at the end of my Java.

Comment: Both questions have been answered on this site: 
[detect activity in background](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3667022/741249)
and [stop mediaplayer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5470068/741249)

If you have multiple mediaplayers I suggest you keep track of the active one(s) in a common class, for example in the [Application class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) if you have one

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a MediaPlayer is null and stop it if it's not.  You could do this for all your MediaPlayers in a Stop button listener or onBackPressed()

```
if (myPlayer != null){
    myPlayer.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to stop the mediaPlayer when the activity finishes.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `stop` and `release` the `mediaPlayer`

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
}
```